# Why does Firefox ignore my globally specified font?

Tags: css, firefox, reset

Hoping that it makes my pages look the same in modern browsers, I included some `reset.css` with the following lines

```
body {
    *font-size: small;
    font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    font: 16px/18px sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

However, the font in my Firefox 20 (for Ubuntu Canonical - 1.0) was still by a few per cent bigger than in my Chromium 25.0.1364.160 Ubuntu 10.04. Funnily, the following rule helped:

```
* {
    font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
}
```

It looks like Firefox overrides the font for span, too, but I can't see it in the Web Developer Tools. It simply chooses a different font, although it shouldn't.

I've created a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/emuncpzFjHQz0XPkdwnT?p=preview) showing it (just drop the star rule to see the change). My questions are

- what's the explanation?
- what's the proper way of resetting styles? Do we really need star rules just in case?

Comment: What are you trying to do with that reset, you are setting the font size then overriding it, then setting the font family then overriding it. It makes no sense

Comment: @svendjokumsen You'd have to ask the author of the reset, not me. No idea where it comes from, it's one of the many public domain `reset.css`.

Comment: Since you chose to use it, I assumed you had and idea of what it did.

Comment: @svendjokumsen No, it's too long and I don't know enough about it - as you can see. So my part was choosing the most popular one according to some site... probably not the best one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation is that `font: 16px/18px sans-serif` sets the font family to `sans-serif`, which is a browser-dependent default sans serif font. It overrides the preceding `font-family` setting. Apparently, in your Firefox, `sans-serif` is mapped to a font that looks smaller than Arial, for the same font size. So the font size is the same, the letters are just smaller.

The simplest fix is to revert the order of the two declarations:

```
body {
    font: 16px/18px sans-serif;
    font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

(The `*font-size` hack is pointless here, since you have a rule later that sets the font size.)

Alternatively, you can combine the rules:

```
body {
    font: 16px/18px arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The question “what's the proper way of resetting styles?” is primarily opinion-based and also independent of the technical problem presented. Setting font properties on `body` isn’t really “resetting styles”, just normal styling. Technically, setting e.g. `font-family` on all elements has a considerable impact, and you should do that only if you really understand the impact (e.g., on form fields, on elements like `code`, etc.).